# Adding dependencies to Clojure projects

Tags: parsing, clojure, project, dependency-management

Quick Clojure question from a Clojure noob:

we need to parse text files for our project, and are looking at using [fnparse](https://github.com/joshua-choi/fnparse/wiki/) to get the job done.

**What do we need to add to project.clj for leiningen to manage this dependency?**

We've already tried adding `[name.choi.joshua.fnparse "2.2"]` to :dependencies, but `lein deps` then fails to find it.

We're worried that maybe we can't use leiningen for this library.  In that case, *are there other good parsing libraries out there for Clojure?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking on [Clojars](http://clojars.org/fnparse), it appears the correct dependency is just `[fnparse "2.2.7"]`.

Comment: Cool!  +1 for introducing me to Clojars!  And +1 for solving the problem (oh wait, only 1 upvote).  Any thoughts on other parser generators for Clojure?

Comment: @MattFenwick: Sorry, don't have much experience with parser generators in Clojure. Hopefully somebody else will have more insight.

Answer (score 4):

I recently dicovered the `lein search` command. is is sometimes incredibly helpful in cases like this:

```
lein search fnparse
 == Results from clojars - Showing page 1 / 4 total
[org.clojars.hiredman/fnparse "2.2.4"] A library for creating functional parsers in Clojure.
[org.clojars.ohpauleez/fnparse "3.0.0alpha4"] A library for creating functional parsers in Clojure.
[fnparse "2.2.7"] A library for creating functional parsers in Clojure.
[fnparse "3.?.4"] A library for creating functional parsers in Clojure.
```